# Pattern matching for return values

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, tuples

I know I can use pattern matching for function parameters like this:

```
fn :: (Integral a) => (a,a) -> (a, a)
fn (x,y) = (y,x)
```

But how can I match the return value? I would expect something like this:

```
g :: (Integral a) => a -> a
g z = do
  (x, y) = fn (z, z + 5)
  x `mod` y
```

This results in a syntax error. Is there a way to match return values? Basically, I want to split the returned tuple into two variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `do` is used a *syntactical sugar* for **monads**. Your function is however not a monad.

What you can do is use a **`let`-clause**, like:

```
g :: (Integral a) => a -> a
g z = let (x,y) = fn (z,(z+5)) in x `mod` y
```

Or a **`where`-clause**:

```
g :: (Integral a) => a -> a
g z = x `mod` y
    where (x,y) = fn (z,(z+5))
```

You can also define a **pattern in a *lambda-expression***, like:

```
g :: (Integral a) => a -> a
g z = (\(x,y) -> x `mod` y) $ fn (z,(z+5))
```

Along these lines, you can also define a **helper function** that does the pattern matching, like:

```
g :: (Integral a) => a -> a
g z = h $ fn (z,(z+5))
    where h (x,y) = x `mod` y
```

This can be useful if there are several patterns that need to be handled differently (like the `Nothing` and `Just x` for the `Maybe a` type).

Say for instance that you defined a function:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
foo x y | x > y = Just x
        | otherwise = Nothing
```

than you can define `bar` with a helper function `qux` to handle the output of `foo`, like:

```
bar :: Int -> Int -> Int
bar x y = qux $ foo x y
    where qux Nothing = y
          qux (Just z) = z
```

Finally in the case of 2-tuples, you can decide **not to use pattern matching**, but use `fst :: (a,b) -> a` and `snd :: (a,b) -> b`, like for instance:

```
g :: (Integral a) => a -> a
g z = let t = fn (z,(z+5)) in ( fst  t) `mod` (snd t)
```

But this is less elegant since here one has to start thinking about what `fst` and `snd` do, and furtermore if not optimized, it can result in additional computation overhead.

Which one to pick depends of course on the context and a bit on personal taste. Since here the pattern is the only one, I would pick the `let` or `where` pattern, but like the French say: "*Les goûts et les couleurs ne se discutent pas.*".

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you tell me which mistake I made in this line? `crt m a = (sum $ ae m a M, M) where M = product m`. I defined `crt :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a] -> (a,a)` and `ae :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a] -> a -> [a]`, but the compiler says `Not in scope: data constructor `M'`.

Comment: Well uppercases are used for constructors. Use a lowercase, like `where pr = product m`.

Comment: Thank you! Having a hard time getting used to haskell.

Comment: "The do is used a syntactical sugar for monads." is a good first approximation to the truth, but just adding a `let` to the `(x,y) = ...` line works as well: http://ideone.com/ZL7QZs

Comment: @DanielWagner it is using the `Identity` Monad instance by default. `x >>= f = f (runIdentity x)` and `return = Identity`.

Comment: @Lazersmoke That code isn't using a monad in `g` at all, despite the `do` "block."

Comment: @Lazersmoke No, there is no `Monad` at use in that code. Just run [the desugaring rules](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) by hand and you will see that none is needed.

Comment: My first thought was "to pattern match over the result of `f x`, one can use a `case f x of ...`". I was very surprised to find a long list of every alternative but that one! :-)

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference in the general case, is to use a `case .. of` expression. For instance, if `f :: Int -> Maybe Int`, we can write

```
g :: Int -> Int
g x = case f x of
   Nothing -> 5
   Just y  -> x+y
```

For types with only one constructor, like tuples, then `let .. in` can also be used:

```
h a = let (x, y) = foo a in ...
```

Remember, however, that `case` is strict while `let` is lazy. E.g.

```
case undefined of (x,y) -> 5
```

raises an error. Instead

```
let (x, y) = undefined in 5
```

evaluates to `5`. So, they are not completely equivalent. They became such when using irrefutable patterns, or matching against a `newtype` constructor.